# Unity android apk is too large

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

In the past few months I've been working on a **2D platform game**, that i'd soon like to publish on the **Google Play Store**.

In the past 2 days, after a few changes, the apk file size increased from around **70MB**, to over **130MB**. I've been thinking about the most recent changes that i did to the app, that might have caused this problem: I imported ***TextMeshPro*** in the project and used it on a few **UI pages** in the game, **added a few small assets** and **created a new scene**.

Another thing that looks wrong to me, is that **the whole Asset folder's size** is slightly less than **60MB**. All the assets that I've manually added are there.

Yesterday I've spent a few hours searching and trying to fix this problem ineffectively. For example by **looking in the editor log**, the files that are really big: for some reason, there were a few **15Mb** **.png** files (when they were only about **300KB**). I decreased their resolution and compressed them, and looking again in the editor log **they had indeed decreased their size, while the apk, still, did not change much** (maybe around 200KB, because the asset files were 300KB before, and only 100KB after).

In conclusion, I have absolutely no idea about why the apk size is so big, and in any way, **I really must bring it back to 60-70MB to upload it on google play store** (being under 100MB).

**Any information or help is really appreciated, thank you!**

**Edit: here is a good part of the build report:**

```
Unloading 309 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
System memory in use before: 92.7 MB.
System memory in use after: 90.0 MB.

Unloading 337 unused Assets to reduce memory usage. Loaded Objects now: 2153.
Total: 384.610600 ms (FindLiveObjects: 0.507000 ms CreateObjectMapping: 0.051800 ms MarkObjects: 382.389300 ms  DeleteObjects: 1.661500 ms)

DisplayProgressNotification: Build Successful
Unloading 1 Unused Serialized files (Serialized files now loaded: 0)
Loaded scene 'Temp/__Backupscenes/0.backup'
    Deserialize:            3.940 ms
    Integration:            333.324 ms
    Integration of assets:  0.050 ms
    Thread Wait Time:       14.688 ms
    Total Operation Time:   352.001 ms
System memory in use before: 196.9 MB.
System memory in use after: 197.0 MB.

Build Report
Uncompressed usage by category (Percentages based on user generated assets only):
Textures               952.7 mb  98.1% 
Meshes                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Animations             0.0 kb    0.0% 
Sounds                 0.0 kb    0.0% 
Shaders                685.8 kb  0.1% 
Other Assets           2.0 mb    0.2% 
Levels                 929.5 kb  0.1% 
Scripts                930.6 kb  0.1% 
Included DLLs          13.3 mb   1.4% 
File headers           339.3 kb  0.0% 
Total User Assets      970.8 mb  100.0% 
Complete build size    2.0 gb
Used Assets and files from the Resources folder, sorted by uncompressed size:
 13.4 mb     0.6% Assets/Graphics/Level 11/ground11.png
 13.4 mb     0.6% Assets/Graphics/Level 3/Lava2.png
 13.0 mb     0.6% Assets/Graphics/Level 12/Trampoline4.png
 12.9 mb     0.6% Assets/Graphics/Level 4/Lava6.png
 12.5 mb     0.6% Assets/Graphics/Level 4/Lava1.png
 12.3 mb     0.6% Assets/Graphics/Level 12/Ground15.png
 11.4 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Backgrounds/Lev19.png
 11.0 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Level 3/Lava5.png
 10.9 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Level 4/Ground13.png
 10.7 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Level 4/Ground12.png
 10.7 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Level 2/Ground1.png
 10.7 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Level 4/Ground6.png
 10.7 mb     0.5% Assets/Graphics/Level 4/Ground8.png
```

Etc.

Comment: What is "editor log"?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 you can see that [here](https://answers.unity.com/questions/9739/how-can-i-find-editor-log-file.html). You can use it for many things, I used to see the **_Build Report_**

Comment: Please post your log.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 What part of the log do you want? It has 2MB of plain text in it ;)

Comment: [This](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html) part.

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 sure, will try to add the most important parts in. The whole build report is around 60.000 characters and the max in stackoverflow seems to be only 30k!

Comment: Could you also provide your apk here?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 Looks like no, sorry. The file is too big. You could give me instructions or ask information that you need, that i can see myself and send to you.

Comment: Can't really help, but for the future or if you project allows it take a look at Unity Project tiny

Answer (score 0):

Few tips to reduce build size on Unity 3d

1. Target project to **NetStandard 2.0** rather than **.Net 4.x** only if project does NOT take a dependency on something like NetCore.App.

> > Unity supports two .NET API compatibility levels.: .NET 4.x and .NET Standard 2.0. The .NET Standard 2.0 restricts you to a smaller subset of the .NET API, which can help keep size down.

2. Compress Meshes and imported Animation Clips so that they take up less space in your game file.

> > To enable Mesh compression, select the Mesh, then in the Inspector window set the Mesh Compression to Low, Medium or High.

3. Compress Textures

> > To do this without modifying the actual source content, select the Texture in the Project view, and in the Inspector window reduce the Max Size. To see how this looks in-game, zoom in on a GameObject that uses the Texture, then **adjust the Max Size until it starts looking worse in the Scene view**.

4. Experimentally build against **arm v7** architecture only , not **x86 + armv7** as fewer devices are on x86

Comment: Thank you, but how can i do the first thing you said? Also, by compressing the assets, it does not change much, as they are only 60MB, and for the reason that i do not know, the apk file size is over 130MB. What could have increased it in that way?